# How should kandra's names be pronounced?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, pronunciation

Almost all of the kandra we meet (and I am halfway through *Shadows of Self* right now, so please no spoilers!) have names with capital letters in the middle of them such as TenSoon, OreSeur, etc.  How should this be pronounced?

In *Shadows of Self,* it is noted that "Milan" and "MeLaan" are pronounced slightly differently, if that helps.  Don't have a page number as of now.

Comment: http://www.17thshard.com/forum/topic/460-pronunciation-guide/?page=2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ATTN: Full page contains spoilers!...

Found [Word of God](https://sites.google.com/site/brandonothology/annotations/mistborn-hoa) in relation to his HoA series

> Sometimes I wish I could crawl inside the heads of my readers while
>   they experience these stories and see what they imagine the places to
>   look like. I've said before that I like how fiction is
>   participatory—that each person who reads my books imagines slightly
>   different things; each person gets different images for places and
>   characters. I'd like to know what they see, just for curiosity's sake.
>   There's no wrong way to imagine these people, just like there isn't a
>   right or a wrong way to pronounce the names. It's all up to you.